# Vue: disable no-unused-vars error: the simplest fix

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a *very simple* vue project:

```
<template>
    <div class="text-breakdown">
        <h3 class = "title">Text Breakdown</h3>

        <form onsubmit="greet()">
            <textarea type="text" id = "breakdown-text"
                  placeholder="Enter your text here">
            </textarea>

            <button class = "custom-button dark-button"
                    type="submit">Breakdown</button>
        </form>
    </div>


</template>


<script>
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

   import axios from 'axios';
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
   function greet()  {
       alert("Hello!");
   }
</script>
```

I get `error  'axios' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars` error which I'm trying to disable. I tried adding `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` comment as I've read in some answers would help, but I still get this error!

**Removing unused variables is not an option, I don't want this error popping up on unused variables!**

**EDIT**: If I put the comment exactly one line above the import:

```
<script>
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
   import axios from 'axios';
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
   function greet()  {
       alert("Hello!");
   }
...
```

I get this in browser console:
[image]
(and localhost never loads - just white screen)

**EDIT**:

I tried adding

```
"rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }
```

to the bottom of the `package.json` file:

```
...
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
  }
}
```

and restarting the server, however the error from the pic above is still present - localhost can't be loaded. The error disappears though if I remove the import altogether.

**EDIT**:

Replacing the `script` tag with:

```
<script>
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        methods: {
            greet()  {
                alert("Hello!");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

works fine. However removing the comment line:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        methods: {
            greet()  {
                alert("Hello!");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Results in the original error, despite me having edited the `package.json` file.

Also, why do I have to add the `export default` syntax when using the `// eslint` comment with the `import`, while just

```
<script>
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    function greet()  {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
</script>
```

is working fine for me?

**ANSWER** (because mods didn't deem the solution important enough to allow edit into existing answers):

This code should be added inside eslintConfig:

```
"rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
```

So that the final `eslintConfig` part of the `package.json` looks like this:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  }
```

After editing the package.json like that and restarting the server, this code doesn't result in the error:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default  {
        methods:  {
            greet()  {
                alert("Hello!");
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

As can be seen the // eslint... comment is no longer necessary.

Comment: Isnt the `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` have to be exactly 1 line above the `import axios`?

Comment: Is this error due to ESLint or are you getting this in vs code due to vetur extension?

Comment: I get this error in `Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):` I get it in browser when going to `localhost`

Comment: Actually he want to exclude  `unused variables` in eslint

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-only-for-a-group-of-files

Comment: Thanks for the note that a restart was required (for me, "react-scripts start").

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You are using eslint, which add rules to your code, `no unused vars` is one of them, which means you aren't allowed to have unused variable in your code, so importing axios variable from `import axios from'axios'` gives you error because you are not using `axios` variable yet. You can ignore rules by:

## 1. Disabling a rule on a line

You can disable a eslint rule on one line by adding `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` above the line you want to disable, for example:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import axios from 'axios';
```

You put your comment in the wrong line, it's supposed to be above `import axios from 'axios';`, so change

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

import axios from 'axios';
```

to

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import axios from 'axios';
```

## 2. Disabling a rule entirely on your project

You can also disable a rule entirely on your project. To do this you need to configure your eslint rules in `package.json` or `.eslintrc.js` depending where you store your eslint configuration.

#### If you choose to store the eslint configuration in `package.json`, add `eslintConfig` key like this:

```
{
    "name": "your-app-name",
    "dependencies": { ... },
    "devDependencies": { ... },
    "eslintConfig": { // Add this <-----
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "babel-eslint"
        },
        "rules": { // rules configuration here <-----
            "no-unused-vars": "off" 
        }
    }
}
```

#### If you choose to store eslint config in `.eslintrc.js`, simply add `rules` key:

```js
module.exports = {
    ...
    rules: {
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
}
```

- Read more about ESLint available rules: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/
- Read more about ESLint Rules Configuration: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

---

About your edit, the `Cannot set property 'render' of undefined` error is caused by the component isn't being exported, this has nothing to do eslint. Change to:

```js
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
   methods: {
      greet()  {
         alert("Hello!");
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

When you are creating a Vue component, you are supposed to export them, read more here:  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: I don't think that's related to eslint, probably you aren't exporting component correctly.

Comment: The code from your edit works! Thank you. However I was wondering why if I remove the `// eslint` comment, the error is still present, considering I've changed `package.json`: added the `rules` there and restarted the server

Comment: It's because you are using eslint on your project, which add rules to your code, `no unused var` is one of them. Read more about what eslint does here: https://eslint.org/docs/about/ , if you want to disable a rule on your eslint project, you have to put it  on your eslint config file, can be `eslintrc.js` or `package.json` (depending on what you pick when you are setting up your eslint)

Comment: I have changed `package.json` however... It didn't seem to have any effect seeing as I'm still forced to add `// eslint` comments on top of that line

Comment: I don't really know how to configure eslint from package.json, i think you need to add `"eslintConfig"` key on the `package.json` object, and inside it you put `"rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }`

Comment: Could you please include the last edit of my question in your answer? For future readers

Comment: Added eslint config for `package.json` and `.eslintrc.js`

Comment: Hey, just tossing my 2 cent (for the witcher :P ) but now apparently you can also disable vuejs elsint plugin rules directly in your template with something like that <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-vars -->

source: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/260#issuecomment-416414771

Comment: Don't forget to restart your dev server after applying the changes.

Answer (score 19):

That would be a rather good idea if you ignore just specific unused variables. For example. let's say, ignore all the variables prefixed by _

Here is how you can do it.

```js
rules: {
  'no-unused-vars': ['warn', {
    argsIgnorePattern: '^_',
    varsIgnorePattern: '^_'
  }]
}
```

Now, any variable (i.e _options) or argument unused, will not create any issue.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me from _"Configuration for rule "no-unused-vars" is invalid"_

Comment: I like this approach, but it flags enum members as breaking the rule.  Not sure how to circumvent that... :/

Answer (score 16):

Add this in package.json file and restart your dev server and rules key should not be twice in the package.json file.

```
"rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }
```

Comment: Where exactly do I need to add it? There is a list of JSON objects there, in which object do I need to put it?

Comment: @parsecer: you must have config file foe eslint

Comment: Now I understand it even less. I do have `package.json`. I added your code to the bottom of the list. Do I need to edit some `foe eslint` file as well?

Comment: rules("rules": {}) json key should not be twice in the package,json file.

Answer (score 11):

If you code just javaScript, do as follows:

```
rules: {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
  },
```

But if you use TypeScript. You must add something more:

```
rules: {
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using 'plugin:vue/essential', so the way to turn off the rule is by adding `'vue/no-unused-vars': "off"` instead of `'no-unused-vars': "off"`  to eslintrc.js

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this your eslintrc file. Do you have have one in your project?

```
"rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To completely disable the no-used-vars, add this into your .eslintrc

```
    "no-unused-vars": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the similar problems and tried many of the above suggestions using the the suggestions. My project is using the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  }, 
   "devDependency:{ "axios": "^0.18.0", ...}
```

I tried putting the code below in my package.json file:

```
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": "off"
}
```

That did not seem to help so in the file where I imported and utilizes axios I added:

```
<script>
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import axios from 'axios';
...
```

This seemed to help the issue of `error  'axios' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars` but I was seeing another issue:

```
WARNING  Compiled with 1 warning                                                                                                                              
warning  in ./src/plugins/axios.js

export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: BaseTransition, Comment, EffectScope, Fragment, . . .
```

At this point, I tried commenting out the plugin import in main.js file and everything worked fine--the last error was eliminated:

```
//import "./plugins/axios";
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

Now everything works fine. Even if I remove all the other modifications I had made to the other files. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: By the way, I using  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0"
  }, and "axios": "^0.18.0", as a devDependency.

Answer (score 1):

In Vue.js, this code does not function:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
```

I modified the syntax slightly, which made it work as intended:

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars */
```

Answer (score 0):

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    "no-unused-vars": "off" 
  }
}
```