# exclude specific key/value pairs by key name when copy contents from one object to another

Tags: javascript

The following example is working correctly, yielding the desired output.  However, I'm wondering if there's a more concise way to do this copy operation by excluding the key/value pairs for keys `created` and `updated` from the `data` object.

```
        const actionMode = 'update';        // 'create';

        const dataFromParent = {
            itemid: "104",
            itemname: "insurance",
            itemtype: "expense",
            unitofmeasure: "$/yr",
            created: "2021-04-14 05:59:30.097",
            updated: "2021-04-14 05:59:30.097"
        }

        const data = { ...dataFromParent }; // make a shallow copy to avoid changing original object values

        if (actionMode == 'update') {
            delete data.created;
            delete data.updated;
        }

        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataFromParent)));
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Console output:
[image]

Using the recommendation posted by @vdegenne on 11/23/2018 in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698905/how-can-i-clone-a-javascript-object-except-for-one-key) I tried:

```
let data = {};

if (actionMode == 'update') {
    data = (({ created, updated, ...o }) => o)(dataFromParent);
}
```

which causes a "Failed to compile" result with these errors:
[image]

**EDIT:**
This modification gives the desired result and does not have any `"no-unused-vars"` errors:

```
        let data = {};

        if (actionMode == 'update') {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
            const { created, updated, ...rest} = { ...dataFromParent };
            data = rest;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue: disable no-unused-vars error: the simplest fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874994/vue-disable-no-unused-vars-error-the-simplest-fix)

Comment: Somewhat.  Since there are no imports causing problems I had to figure out where to put that statement.  I'll edit the original question to show what changes worked.

Comment: Is it worked after adding the comment?

Comment: Yes, that looked after the `"no-unused-vars"` errors.  Hooray!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) so that it will assign `created`, `updated` values, and rest other properties assign in a single object.

As you are using VUE, so add the following snippet before all import in `script` tag in `x.vue file`. [SEE FOR VUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874994/vue-disable-no-unused-vars-error-the-simplest-fix)

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
```

**[Disallow Unused Variables (no-unused-vars)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)**

If error still persist then change the `ESLint` config in package.json

```
"rules": {
   "no-unused-vars": "off"
}
```

```js
const dataFromParent = {
  itemid: "104",
  itemname: "insurance",
  itemtype: "expense",
  unitofmeasure: "$/yr",
  created: "2021-04-14 05:59:30.097",
  updated: "2021-04-14 05:59:30.097",
};

const { created, updated, ...rest } = dataFromParent; // make a shallow copy to avoid changing original object values
const data = rest;

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Bro see the time I've answered `7 min ago ` and yours `2 min ago`.

Comment: Yes, the "no-unused-vars" error persists.  I was hoping to find a way to do this without turning "no-unused-vars" off since I find that useful most of the time.

Comment: Are you using any framework like `vue` or something else

Comment: Yes, I'm using Vue.

Comment: @RanTurner See the history. Please see first then comment. What I've edited and When I've answered.

Comment: Just use `// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars` before all import in `script`

Comment: Is `axios` part in the answer above to give an example of an otherwise unused var, to demonstrate how the `// eslint-disable-next line no-ununsed-vars` works?

Comment: No it is just an example to add comment before all imports

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread to exclude properties.

```js
const dataFromParent = {
            itemid: "104",
            itemname: "insurance",
            itemtype: "expense",
            unitofmeasure: "$/yr",
            created: "2021-04-14 05:59:30.097",
            updated: "2021-04-14 05:59:30.097"
}

const { created, updated, ...data} = {...dataFromParent };
  
console.log(data);
```