# Vuex 11:17 error 'state' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Hi I have an error in Vuex

11:17  error  'state' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

I can't find anything about this
and here is the code

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0,
  },
  getters: {
    increment: (state) => this.state.count++,
  },
});
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ this.$store.state.count }}
    <button @click="increment">increment</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      this.$store.getters.increment;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: The `state` is passed as an argument but never used inside `increment` getter body. Either use `increment: (state) => state.count++` or `increment: () => this.state.count++`

Comment: `increment: () => this.state.count++` will rise an error as `this` is undefined in vuex getters. the error in question is a linting error, and can be safely turned off in `.eslintrc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61874994/vue-disable-no-unused-vars-error-the-simplest-fix

Comment: @IgorMoraru It's not preferable to turn it off as it often indicates problems in the code like this one. The use of `state` suggest that it should be `(state) => state.count++` but instead it's accessed on `this` without a good reason and in a wrong way. This linter error also commonly occurs when there's a problem with scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `this.state.count++`, do `state.count += 1` as `state` is being passed as an argument to getter. Although I am not sure why `state` is being mutated by a getter. (use mutations).

Comment: @NardisAbbas now i have another error    6:1   error  Prefer default export     import/prefer-default-export
  11:27  error  Unary operator '++' used  no-plusplus

Comment: instead of `state.count++`, please do `state.count += 1`. This is just an `eslint` rule Because the unary ++ and -- operators are subject to automatic semicolon insertion, differences in whitespace can change semantics of source code.